# Spark - org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc): bad symbolic reference

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to code very simple script in Spark (using Scala) to write and read parquet files. Using this [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) I wrote the following code:

```
package com.mygroup

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import  org.apache.spark.sql

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val logFile = "C:/MyDocs/test.txt" // Should be some file on your system
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    //Tutorial to count words in a file
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")

    //HERE STARTS THE PROBLEMATIC PART
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    //Open a parquet file
    //logData.write.parquet("logData.parquet")

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

But in `val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)` I am getting the following error message:

> bad symbolic reference. A signature in SQLContext.class refers to term
>   internal in package org.apache.spark which is not available. It may be
>   completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the
>   classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling
>   SQLContext.class.

So as I understand the problems may be that I am not adding the correct dependency or a version incompatibility between the compiler and the classpath.

My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Not sure if `spark-sql_2.10` is the correct artifact for this. Here an image to show the spark-sql_2.10 is added in my project.

[image]

From this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.implicits$.html) I learnt that SQLContext is available since 1.3.0. I am using Scala installation 2.10.6 (built in) and target jvm 1.6. So that should not be an issue.

In case it may be relevant I using as well [J2SE - 1.5] and my IDE is Spring Tool Suite 3.8.2 (Eclipse)

Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Ok solved after changing to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Following the solution in Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in SQLContext.class refers to type Logging in package org.apache.spark which is not available

So this my quesiton should be marked as duplicated

Answer (score 1):

I would not depends on spark-sql 2.0.0 AND spark-core 1.6.2 at the same time..  Adjust your dependencies.